# What does the sentence mean, and is it grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?
And is it grammatically correct?

> You will always find a person in your life who enjoys other people suffering.

Answer (score 2):

First we will break down the sentence to see if it's grammatically correct:

> `You (subject)` will always `find (verb)` a person in your life who enjoys other people suffering.

With the main subject and verb in a sentence, it can be considered grammatically correct.

How do the other parts (aka non-essential clauses, which means they can be removed and still have a complete sentence) play a role in this sentence:

`will always` describes when you will `find (verb)`
`a person` describes what you will `find (verb)`
`in your life` describes where is `a person`
`who enjoys other people suffering` describes what `a person` enjoys

---

What it means:

A sentence can have different meanings in different contexts. I would think that the most common meaning of this sentence would what it says.

In case you don't understand, this is a way to rephrase the sentence:

> In your life, there will always be someone that enjoys seeing other people suffer.

Sorry if it's still not clear, since I would think that is pretty understandable already.